# Typescript: restrict field type and infer rest fields

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

The question is how to tell TypeScript to infer generic param of certain `fn` call with literals as `{ field: Union, extra: number }`? If I omit `<>` block completely for `fn` *call*, the type would be inferred as `{ field: string, extra: number }`.

```
type Union = 'a' | 'b';

function fn<T>(arg: T[]) { /* ... */ }

fn<infer ? extends { field: Union }>([{
  field: 'a',
  extra: 1,
}, {
  field: 'b',
  extra: 2,
}])
```

Solutions I know, but which don't suit my needs.

- use enums—needs too many changes
- typecast every `field` value — repetitive and miss some type errors
- write `T extends { field: Union }` in `fn` delcaration—I want `fn` to be generic. I'm inclining towards this option, by declaring a new `fn2` function for that.

Comment: Turned out there are enums, so I have a solution. But if at some point there would be an ability to solve the problem as I wrote with TypeScript, consider adding an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach you could take is to declare the `fn` signature in such a way as to hint to infer the narrowest possible type for its argument.  This isn't exactly the same as what you're asking for, but at least the `fn` call won't forget the literals, and you can widen the type as needed afterward.

It would be nice if there were some [simple way to ask for the narrowest generic type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680), but there isn't right now.  Instead we have to jump through a lot of hoops:

```
type Narrowable = string | number | boolean | symbol
  | object | undefined | void | null; 

declare function fn<
  N extends Narrowable,
  T extends N | { [k: string]: N | T | [] }
>(x: T[]): void;
```

That doesn't change much about what you're allowed to pass into `fn` (you can still do `fn([1, 2, 3])` if you want), but the inferred type of `T` becomes much more specific:

```
fn([
  {
    field: "a",
    extra: 1
  },
  {
    field: "b",
    extra: 2
  }
]);
// T inferred as { field: "a"; extra: 1; } | { field: "b"; extra: 2; }
```

If you like the general idea but are not happy with the weird black magic needed to get that narrower inference, you might want to go to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680) and give it a .

---

On the other hand you can use a [`const` assertion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#const-assertions) in the call to `fn()`, as long as you allow `fn()` to accept `readonly` arrays as well as regular arrays:

```
declare function fn2<T>(x: ReadonlyArray<T>): void;

fn2([
  {
    field: "a",
    extra: 1
  },
  {
    field: "b",
    extra: 2
  }
] as const); 
// T inferred as | { readonly field: "a"; readonly extra: 1; } 
//               | { readonly field: "b"; readonly extra: 2; }
```

This cause a similar type to be inferred for `T` (give or take `readonly` vs read-write properties), but the request for narrowing happens by the caller instead of by the declaration of `fn`.

---

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAcghgJwQewO5wEYBtoF4oDOwCAlgHYDmUAPlGQK4C2GECNUGyyOcZ7BIZtwBQUdsgwArCAGNg7emQAmEAGbkIS9gDdkJLbQZYsAbmHCVMrImirFcksj6qyAHlGwoEAB7AIyglhEFHRsCAAaDwAVL19-JUCYdgBvKABtAGsALkJicgoAXRyk2hjaNIKoAF9hAD4ACm8cqIqAShzdfTNhF3q0j2SPMXUILCUcgCI4CcixMR9iOByARg8q2ahBuagRscmMGaHYxZyAJjXhAtazAHobqBjyVVYETSg4QNTd8agpiZNjggllBlgCqikdiRRj8JgcAQsgWcweYLLJrK8dvZgI5nGRTq4og0mlAAEoQOBKJxYEAAQSQcBABNq7SgnSU3Rcpz6AyO30m0w2818iJBaw2WzmfN+B0FgOB5zENUqHygMicRGuUGEdweUCeLzeKtoqVeFKpIEh0P5-ygpspZGpcpWYK1Ou27vdxtt5PtjqlsJtdvNTqgp2RKOEQA)

Comment: I like the idea of `as const`, it seems keeping types as narrow as possible.

Comment: But for some reason it doesn't work further down the road. Maybe, it's mutated inside `fn`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe parameterize the type you are trying to infer from (`Union`)? Otherwise, try explaining what you are expecting with examples.

```
type Union = 'a' | 'b';

function fn<T extends Union>(arg: { field: T, extra: number }[]) { /* ... */ }

fn([{
  field: 'a',
  extra: 1,
}, {
  field: 'b',
  extra: 2,
}])
```

Comment: This is the third option I listed at the end of my answer, a known, but not preferable.

Comment: I see. Beware though that `T extends { field: Union }` is different from `T extends Union` (check the inferred type of `fn(...)`).

Answer (score 0):

How about typecasting the array before calling? (Not recommended as it swallows errors, Use second approach if you need type safety)

```
type Union = 'a' | 'b';
type CustomType = {
  field: Union,
  extra: number
}

function fn<T>(arg: T[]) {}

fn([{
  field: 'a',
  extra: 1,
}, {
  field: 'b',
  extra: 2,
}] as CustomType[])
```

Or maybe assign it to that type before passing:

```
type Union = 'a' | 'b';
type CustomType = {
  field: Union,
  extra: number
}
function fn<T>(arg: T[]) {}

let x:CustomType[] = [{
  field: 'a',
  extra: 3,
}, {
  field: 'b',
  extra: 2,
}]

fn(x)
```

Comment: The second option is definitely better. `as` is a forced cast, if there's a typo like `field: 'c'` cast will swallow en error.

Comment: Actually, even more local `field: 'c' as Union` allows that kind of error. And cast on whole array allows other type of typos like `field: 1`. Just play with values and try to break things—you'll see how dangerous is `as Type`.

Comment: agreed the first option swallows the error, I will update the answer to mention it is swallows the error.